# Is there any difference in API calling for development and production for Apple's DeviceCheck?

Tags: ios, device, identification, devicecheck

I am using Apple's DeviceCheck API in my Swift application which will check if the device is registered on Apple's server or not and based on the bits I have set I am updating the values in my own database. These values will help me to differentiate the new devices through which the users are getting logged in to my application and I will give them some digital reward poits to use my application on their new devices.

Everything is working fine for me in the development environment as I get the right response when I am using the development API i.e. https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com but it do not work as intended when I am using the production API i.e. https://api.devicecheck.apple.com/

I have tried both APIs but the response from development API is right and in production API it always returns **400 Missing or incorrectly formatted bits**

Comment: Are you calling the production api from a TestFlight or App Store released build?  You can't call it from an Xcode build.

Comment: Yes, I am calling the production API from the App Store released build.

Comment: Are you getting this error on setting or reading the bits?  If you are getting it on reading, it is expected if you have never set buts for this device.

Comment: I am facing this issue on both operations. Reading & Writing

Comment: Do you get the same error with https://api.devicecheck.apple.com/v1/validate_device_token as well?

Comment: What is this link? And how can I check this? Can you please provide link to its documentation?